# A smile "plays about one's lips"? Shouldn't it be "plays on one's lips"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms

I have seen quite a few places where *a smile plays about one's lips* comes up

> When Elise saw these things that were so dear to her heart, **a smile played about her lips** and the blood came back to her cheeks at the thought of being able to save her brothers.
>
> She leaned back, her eyes closed and **a light smile played about her lips**.

[This page](http://nyanglish.com/smile-played-about-her-lips) has plenty of examples from real-life sources, and so does Google Books.

I can't understand why the preposition "about" appears here, instead of "on." A smile, as far as I understand, should **play on** one's lip, and *play about* means to *play around*. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A smile involves more than one's lips --- it includes the whole face. In fact, the lips are often the last facial feature involved. So a smile playing about one's lips is a smile happening around the mouth, and probably starting to affect the mouth. It's the beginning of a smile, a smile threatening to break full on to someone's face.